# An error occured processing your request

Tags: plasticscm

I have 5.0.44.598 - Mahon version of Plastic SCM, the latest one by today(25 Aug,2014)

This is the first time I will be using Plastic SCM.

I keep getting "An error occured processing your request"  error message when I click on branch explorer. Also whenever client software is opening first time.

I have win7 machine and also a win server 2012 on azure; have the same problem in both systems.

Does any one have the same problem, or any resolution?
I think it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Could you enable the Plastic client log? (http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/kb-enabling-logging-for-plastic-scm-part-i.aspx), and send the stack trace to: support@codicesoftware.com

I´ve tested the same version in my local Win7 machine and the branch explorer is properly working.

- Could you delete the file: "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\plastic4\guivisualstate.xml" and restart the Plastic client.
- If you create a new workspace, does the issue persist?
- Do you have enabled any external extension (issue tracker...)?

UPDATE: Reviewed the logs and sent a solution to @freewill. If a similar issue happens again please contact to: support@codicesoftware.com

Regards.

Comment: none of the suggestions worked. I sent the log file to the given email address

Comment: UPDATE: Reviewed the logs and sent a solution to @freewill. If a similar issue happens again please contact to: support@codicesoftware.com